# Resources for finding first real job after completing degree

Tags: job-search, education, canada

I recently completed school with my degree in Computer Science. Are there any resources for finding specifically entry level jobs? I’ve been to a few job websites and there are so many that instantly don’t apply to me, for example have the word “senior” in the title. I’ve tried using LinkedIn jobs and setting it to entry level, but for whatever reason the filter doesn’t work properly. Is there some sort of search engine I can use to filter out jobs that are clearly not for recent grads? I’ve also been using Craigslist and Indeed but (as far as I can find) there’s no way to filter out jobs that require a lot of experience.

While I had several work terms as co-op placements, these don’t amount to the 5+ years experience most job openings require. So I do have some experience, though I'm not sure co-op placement counts as experience.

I have considered looking for work with companies I had done co-op placements with, though this doesn't really work. I don't want to move cities and many of the co-ops I worked at were startups and not hugely successful. The one company I did a co-op at I would like to work for, I contacted and they said they don't have any openings in the city I am in.

TL;DR are there any websites that can filter for junior or enters level tech jobs?

Comment: A good move is to always try to grab a job while doing your courses, if possible. I started working as a C# dev during my first semester on college, and when I finished college I already had 5 years of experience under my belt. That facilitated a lot of things in the long run!

Comment: Getting that first job is hard enough anyway, without limiting your search to a single city. Consider moving for now, even if you intend to look for a job back in your current home city after you have more experience.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere sadly they were very useless

Comment: A location tag would be helpful here - I could recommend websites for the UK which allow you to filter on level of experience required, but if you're in the US or elsewhere, this might not be helpful.

Comment: Finding a job can be tough without the constraint of needing to be in your city.  Since you are way more likely to get hired if you have a contact, I'd suggest networking at events that are likely to have people in your industry.  Hackathons, professional association meetings, maker spaces, etc are likely places to meet people employed in tech.  Once you have an in, a company not advertising an open position is a much smaller barrier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious thing that springs to mind is to alter your searches on job sites to look for the word "Junior" or "Graduate" - many job titles and recruitment listings will specifically include these words to indicate entry-level positions or positions suitable for fresh graduates.

Also, many job/recruitment websites allow you to filter based on the experience required. For example, in the UK (where I live), on [Reed](http://www.reed.co.uk/jobs), they have a "Suitable for Graduates" filter which can be applied to search results:

[image: ReedFilter]

If you search LinkedIn for jobs, they also have an experience level filter:

[image: LinkedInSearch]

I have seen similar filters on a bunch of different job websites, so if the site(s) you are currently using don't have this option, find one which does!

Another option is to speak to and/or register with recruitment agencies and have them find positions for you with the specific criteria of wanting entry-level/graduate positions. Bear in mind though that recruiters are motivated to put you forward for any positions they think there is even the slimmest chance you might be able to get offered, so you may have to be quite forceful about only wanting to be put forward for these more junior positions.

And yes, as others have mentioned, asked your University - most educational establishments have some links with industry and may be able to find you positions to apply for.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, when I get to Linked In jobs it shows a different filter with a sliding bar. How exactly did you get this one?

Comment: I went to [Jobs](https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/) from the homepage, typed some text into the search box (labelled "Job title, keywords, or company name" before I entered any text) and clicked "Find Jobs", this filter was then shown on the left hand side of the results, towards the bottom of the list of available filters. I've updated the screenshot in my answer to better illustrate.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your college/university. Many of them have job assistance centers either at the school or the department level. During the semester many hold job fairs to not only find positions for internships but also jobs after graduation.

Yes I know you graduated but many will allow recent graduates to use their services.

They can also help with reviewing resumes and practice interviews.

Comment: I tried this, they were very unhelpful :( Though I had gone to another school several years ago with a better co-op department/work placement program so maybe I'll contact them.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know which country you are in, but when i graduated in Computer Science a few months ago I found that ordinary job search sites such as https://www.monster.co.uk/ and http://www.jobsite.co.uk/ where helpful.

It's also worth noting that most applications will go through recruitment agencies, so once a few of those have your details then they will contact you whenever a suitable position comes their way. Most of these sites also give you the option to make your resume public, so that way recruiters can look at it and will call you up if they have a suitable job role. I would often get multiple calls each day this way. A good tip is to also update your resume on these sites regularly as it pushes you to the top of the list and more recruiters will see it.